# Pagination for huge data records

Tags: php, database, memcached, sphinx

Need help or advice for pagination for huge records.

I have 400,000 records, while doing pagination every time it's going to db and getting set records based on limit set.

we tried adding all the records into session(which is not good options)after 60thousand records session values is not getting stored.

Need to know any other methods can help in pagination huge data records.

Can i use sphinx/memcache for this?

Comment: [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh) 1 lakh = 100,000.

Comment: I edited the question. Lakh is practically never used outside India.

Comment: Can you supply the schema of the table as well as the database server name?

Answer (score 2):

So what is the issue? Database queries are supposed to be hitting the database. is there a performance problem? that can be remedied with proper indexes. 400k really isn't a huge dataset even if your are limiting to 10-20 results.

`EXPLAIN` will help you to see what your sql server is doing.

If pagination is refreshing the page, you probably want to implement AJAX for a more seemless ux.

You can use both sphinx or memcached.  Memcached could be easier to implement beucase you can just search the cache first before hitting the DB.  I think that some query/db tuning can go a long way.

Answer (score 1):

you could retrieve the records using AJAX, e.g. 100 records at a time

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in memory using memcache, that would work but it might take up a lot of memory.

If your data set has a key that is incremented, using a time or a primary key auto_increment field, you can do a query that would look like follows.

```
SELECT fieldlists FROM tablename WHERE key > $lastusedkey limit $limit
```

this would get by the bottleneck that limit can cause in applications that do paging and it does not require you to put the entire database into memory.